# finding the function without taylor series expansion

Tags: functions

It's given that $\frac{{d}^2y}{{d}x^2}=y$ , can we prove that y= a$e^x$ + b$e^{-x}$.

I can do so by taylor series , but i was hoping to find another method because it is not provided that function is infinitely derivable.

Comment: How are you defining $e^x$?

Comment: thats my doubt actually , that is there such a function which is not infinitely derivable but satisfies above condition.

Comment: Well, if you had two functions satisfying the ODE and given initial conditions, say $y(0)=a,y'(0)=b$, then their difference would satisfy the ODE with initial conditions $y(0)=y'(0)=0$, so your doubt becomes can we find such a function which is not identically 0.

Comment: i am sorry but i did not get you at all , could you explain further.Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this is a special  case of standard facts about differential equations.  Here's a proof using nothing at all:

Define $$z=y'+y.$$Then $$z'-z=0,$$so $$(z(t)e^{-t})'=0,$$hence  $$z=ae^t.$$In other words, $$y'+y=ae^t.$$So $$(y(t)e^t)'=ae^{2t},$$so $$ye^t=ae^{2t}+b.$$

### Where did that come  from?

If $D$ denotes the operation of differentiation we have $$0=(D^2-1)y=(D-1)(D+1)y=(D-1)z.$$The standard method for solving first-order linear equations says $z=$something; hence $y'+y=$something, another first-order liner equation.

What's above is that argument written in a more elementary style. Heh, the moral is that a nice thing about the standard method for  solving first-order linear equations is that it contains a proof that it's right...

Comment: thanks appreciate a lot

Comment: +1 I like the elegance of the above. But the OP commented that he is worried that the exponential solution might not be the **only** solution. To deal with that point, I think one has to appeal to something like the [Picard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

Comment: @almagest ??? Look again - I _proved_ that $y=ae^t+be^{-t}$.

Comment: Using only that $w'(t)=0$ for all $t$ implies $w$ is constant. I guess you are right. That special case is easier to prove.

Comment: @almagest So I exaggerated when I said it used nothing at all - the reader needs to know first-semester calculus...